# Angular Directive - How to add an anchor and set routerlink to a dom element

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-directive

I want to create a structural direcive which turns the following

```
<any-dom-element anchorDirective="baseRoute">{{itemId}}</any-dom-element>
```

to

```
<any-dom-element>
    <a [routerLink]="[baseRoute, itemId]">{{itemId}}</a>
</any-dom-element>
```

sofar I have

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[anchorDirective]' })
export class AnchorDirective {
    @Input() set sbAnchor(baseRoute: string) {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = baseRoute;
        // <------ How to insert the anchor, so that it will work with angulars router?
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
    }
    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

So my questions are

1. How to insert the created anchor
2. How to make the created anchor work with angulars router?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your two specific questions is: It's not possible.

As of Angular 8, it's not possible to add a directive (`routerLink` in this case) to any element dynamically. There is an [open issue on the Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785) about ability to apply a directive to a component host element. While this issue is not exactly what you are looking for they share some commonality. If it was possible to dynamically add a directive to any element then it would also be possible to apply it to a component host element.

If you do not care about the specific implementation details of your sought after feature, then below is a suggestion for an alternative approach.

I suggest implementing your anchor as a component that has an attribute selector instead of a structural directive:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[anchor]', // <-- The component selector can be an attribute, it doesn't have to be an element tag.
  templateUrl: './anchor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./anchor.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AnchorComponent implements OnInit {}
```

With this approach you can now populate your component template with whatever Angular goodness you want :)

The component can be used as follows:

```
<div [anchor]="baseRoute"></div>
```

or

```
<h1 [anchor]="baseRoute"></h1>
```

or

```
<p [anchor]="baseRoute"></p>
```

etc...

This approach does not work however if you need to be able to apply the component on another component. Example:

```
<some-angular-component [anchor]="baseRoute"></some-angular-component>
```

If you tried to do this you would get the following runtime console error:

```
Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
```

Comment: thanks for the input about component selector as attribute. However it doesn't answer the 2 questions Ive posted below. I want to know how to insert Dom elements with structural directives and in this this case apply the  routing feature

Comment: I agree I did not answer your two specific questions. I have updated my answer. Hopefully that is more helpful.